# sublimetext 3 disable autocomplete upon pressing enter

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

There is this behaviour of sublimetext that I want to disable/change:

when sublimetext shows popup of an autocomplete suggestion, if I press enter, it will autocomplete that suggestion instead of making a newline... I do not want that.

For example:

```
def getuname(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as fo:
            uname = json.load(fo)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    else:
        return username
```

upon typing `None` and pressing enter, it would autocomplete `None` to `FileNotFoundError` since the letters in None are in FileNotFoundError.. I can press press space and then press enter but this really bothers me when writing code...

How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `Preferences > Settings >` you can view a document `Default/Preferences.sublime_settings` that has a value:

`"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false`

that you should change to `true` and then it will switch completion from using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to using <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Documentation for `auto_complete_commit_on_tab`:

> By default, auto complete will commit the current completion on enter.
> This setting can be used to make it complete on tab instead.
> Completing on tab is generally a superior option, as it removes
> ambiguity between committing the completion and inserting a newline.

Note: You should make the changes in the second file in the split context window (`User/Preferences.sublime_settings`).